# Property management software to manage a few rented flats

Tags: windows, android, web-apps

I am looking for a computer program if it's an app then for Android if it's a program then for Windows and ok if it an online website.

I rent flats in my house, but not like an estate agent, just 3 flats in my house. I want a program with the following primary features:

1. Which can store information of my tenants like name, id, phone number etc.
2. Should send mail/SMS on 5th of every month to deposit the rent.
3. Sends a receipt email after the rent is deposited (manual as I accept only cash).

and any other features are appreciated.

Comment: Step 3 might be very difficult. What forms of payment do you accept?

Comment: Ahh no, no need to link with bank. I accept only in cash. I want to just mail it manually through the software.

Comment: It might be simplest to 1) set an alarm on your own calendar to remind you to send the reminder SMS and 2) when you get cash, send an SMS (although, if that is meant to act as a receipt, it probably ought to be written). This seems too simple for someone to have developed an app to do it. Also - and I don't say this applies to you - but if I were renting cash in hand and not reporting the income I wouldn't want to have SMSs like that lying around ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for editing my question to let me know that it is called as Property Management Software.

I found an app to do it. Its called as [Property Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.propertymanager&hl=en) on play store.

Comment: Just post a link as well to the app and some screenshots when possible.